# What is the inverse kernel of this integral transform?

Tags: integral-transforms, integral-kernel, tag-removed

I am looking for the associated inverse kernel to the integral transform $T$ defined by

$(Tf)(u) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} K(u,t)f(t) \ dt,\ \ u \in \mathbb{R^+}$

whose kernel is $K(u,t) = \frac{2cu}{c^2u^2+4\pi^2(u-t)^2}$
for a given $c > 0$.

Edit:  this other form of the integral transform may help:

$(Tf)(u) = \int_{-\infty}^{0} \hat{f}(s)\exp((2i\pi+c)us)\ ds + \int_{0}^{+\infty} \hat{f}(s)\exp((2i\pi-c)us)\ ds$,

where $\hat{f}$ is the Fourier transform of $f$. What I need is a [closed-form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) of the inverse kernel $K^{−1}$.

Note that for $f(t) = \exp(2i\pi at)$, one has:
\begin{align*}
(Tf)(u) & = & \exp((2i\pi-c)au) \ \rm if \ \it a \rm\geq 0,\\
&  & \exp((2i\pi+c)au) \ \rm if \it \ a \rm \leq 0,\\ 
\end{align*}
that is, $T$ introduces in the usual Fourier basis an exponential decay whose rate $ca$ increases linearly with the frequency $a$.

Comment: $\lim_{c\rightarrow 0}(Tf)(u)=f(u)$.

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker : thank you for your comment. You are perfectly right, but I need the expression of $K^{-1}$ for $c > 0$.

Comment: if, as you say, you only know $(Tf)(u)$ for $u>0$, then I don't think you will be able to invert it to obtain $f(t)$; the small-$c$ limit already tells you why: you will not be able to find $f(t)$ for negative $t$; on the other hand, if you know $(Tf)(u)$ for any complex $u$, then a contour integration allows you to recover $f(t)$ --- just try $c=2\pi$ and you see that $(Tf)(z/2-iz/2)$ gives you $f(z)$.

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker : what I need is the expression of the inverse kernel $K^{-1}$ (as an explicit function of two variables), not a mean for computing $f(t)$ knowing $(Tf)(u)$.
One thing that may help is this other form of the integral transform:

$(Tf)(u) = \Re(\int_{0}^{+\infty} \hat{f}(s)\exp((2i\pi-c)us)\ ds)$.

I will add this to the initial question.

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker : erm... are you sure about $(Tf)(z/2−iz/2)$ gives $f(z)$? It holds for $f(t) = \exp(2i\pi at)$ if $a \geq 0$ but not if $a < 0$. In the latter case you would need to use instead $(Tf)(z/2+iz/2)$.

Comment: sure, it depends on how you have to close the contour, either in the upper or lower half of the complex plane

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker : OK, thank you. What do you think, is there a hope for obtaining a closed-form of $K^{-1}$?